# Usage of "deads" and "deaths"

Tags: synonyms, word-usage

And major difference?

"10 deaths" vs "10 deads", what is the difference?

Comment: Have you found "deads" in a dictionary?

Answer (score 4):

Never "10 deads."  You can say "10 dead," which refers to the number of people killed in an incident:  At the bus accident, there were ten dead and five wounded.  You might say "10 deaths" to relate to the acts of dying themselves:  There were ten deaths at XYZ Hospital in October.  Five deaths were due to drug overdoses, three deaths were due to complications from surgery, and the other two deaths are still under investigation.  Note reference to the deaths themselves, not the people who died.

Comment: What is it about English that constrains a native speaker from using *dead* as a noun? Is it absolutely impossible for *dead* to be used as a noun? If so, how come?

Comment: @Clare Because "dead" doesn't have a semantic function as a noun.  The noun "death" means the transition from living to not living.  "His death was a slow and painful one."  "Dead" in "there were 10 dead" is short for "10 people dead," in which case it's an adjective.  It follows the pattern of "10 wounded, 10 missing, 10 safe and accounted for."

Comment: But speakers can use words in manners that change their semantic function can't they? Like verbing of nouns and vice versa?

Comment: @Clare That is true; they say you can verb any noun.  But for it to become accepted usage, it has to be done repeatedly by many people. You can't just start doing it and expect it to show up in the dictionary the next day.  So as of November 2017, "10 deads" sounds like something an English language learner might say by mistake.